Azure Function Lifecycle and Configuration Best Practice
I'm trying to understand the best practices around reading configuration used by an Azure Function. Currently I can't find any detailed Microsoft documentation.
Scenario
I have an Azure Function using an Azure Service Bus (ASB) Topic/Subscription Trigger. It is written in C# and hosted in an App Service Plan.
The Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription currently receives a few dozen messages per day,  but a future plan is for it to start receiving 10,000s of messages and the function needs to process them quickly (due to SLA requirements).
The function needs to write the message payload to several data stores (blob storage and databases).
Currently configuration for logging, blob and database connection strings are held as Environment Variables and accessed in the Function Run method using code similar to:
public class ProcessMetricsData
{
   [FunctionName("ProcessMetricsDataEvents")]
   public async Task Run(
       [ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "SourceAsbConn")]
       ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
       ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
   {
       var dbConn = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EncryptedDatabaseConn");
       var dbService = new DataManagementService(dbConn);
       await dbService.SaveRawMessageAsync(message);

       // do other tasks
   }
}

The future ASB messages will be submitted as part of multiple sessions.
There is a new requirement to hold sensitive configuration information in Azure Key Vault..

There are ~ 10-15 variables I want to put in Azure Key Vault.
Since there is a high performance requirement, I'm concerned about the volume of configuration requests made to Azure Key Vault, and whether I will get timeouts reading secret values.
The Azure Key Vault secrets are static and only change in conjunction with either an Azure Function deployment or stop/start event.

My concerns are really from a lack of understanding of how an Azure Function is instantiated, its lifecycle and destruction.
Questions
My questions are related to the lifecycle of an Azure Function and how configuration should be read from a best practice perspective.
In an ideal world I'd read the Azure Key Vault secrets once, and the values would be available until the function was redeployed or stop/started. I'd rather read 20 variables once, rather than 10,000s events * 20 AKV secrets!
I already have a singleton service class that reads AKV secrets and outputs as an IDictionary<string, string> collection.

Is there any good documentation that describes Azure Function lifecycle with for example UML sequence diagrams that explains the process flow?
Is there a method override that is a startup method (i.e. run once per startup event) ?
Is Dependency injection (DI) the way to go?

Is DI run once per startup event? (start/stop/redeployment)
or run once per function instantiation (i.e. for each message)?
Can I just use my Singleton service class within DI ?


Does the fact I'm using an App Service Plan mean that my function is kept loaded in memory and therefore I could use a static variable(s) to hold configuration, or would DI naturally run only once at startup?

Summary
Any help understanding the lifecycle would be much appreciated, especially since I'm aware I lack knowledge of the internal Azure Function technical processes. Most of the documentation I've read tells the:

"How to do Dependency Injection" for logging or service code
"How to read Environment Variables"

However, there seems to be very little about the Azure Function Host, lifecycle, background info and scenarios I've described above.
Thank you in advance :-)

What is the version of your app?

AFAIK,there is no limit to store secrets in KeyVault.Instead of retrieving the secrets from keyvault directly,you can store the reference in App Settings of the deployed Function app and retrieve them using Environment variables.

Its dotnet v6 at the moment with the plan to upgrade to v8 as part of the changes.

I don't have any concerns with the number of stored secrets, my question is about where to put the code that reads the secrets so I'm reading them all once. Would you mind expanding your thoughts on storing in appsetting and retrieving using Environment variables please? I'm using EnvVars atm but I'm being asked to store secrets in AKV and take them out of the Environment Variables that are populated at deployment time, and instead read them at runtime; I'm not sure how your option helps?

Ok..will look into it and let you know

Referencing the keyvault secrets in App settings allows you to retrieve values easily with Environment Variables.

Instead of DI,try this approach and check once.

Any update on this?

Thank you, unfortunately that doesn't help me understand where to write the code that retrieves the secrets. If the EnvVariables contain AKV resource links, and they are read for every message received (and they in turn read from Key Vault at that time i.e. stateless) then that doesn't solve my problem which is to reduce the impact on calling the Azure Key Vault. I don't want to ask Key Vault for 20 secrets every time I receive a ASB message, I want to get 20 secrets once, store them in memory, only when the function is restarted. I don't know whether this is possible.

Refer this SOThread once.

It sounds like you might want a service registered as a Singleton in the DI, which would only need to get your AKV when the instance is started from cold. (Although, how often that happens will depend on usage pattern and App Service Plan.) I can write a code sample answer if it would help? Singleton info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection
